# Sql запрос с группировкой со связью многие ко многим

Tags: sql, firebird

Здравствуйте уже долго сижу над одним вопросом, и не получается сделать запрос с верной группировкой. Работа происходит с таблицами Departments, teachers, teachersanddepartments. Так получилось, что в институте один преподаватель может быть закреплен за несколькими кафедрами (от 1 до 3). Необходимо сделать запрос с группировкой по преподавателю, чтоб у него отображались все кафедры к которым он принадлежит и не было дублирования как на скрине ниже. Красным выделено то, что должно быть одной строкой, но в name_of_department необходимо отобразить два названия кафедры к которым принадлежит преподаватель. 
Помогите пожалуйста

[image: запрос в данное время]
[image: таблица БД]

Comment: в группировку колонки id_teacher, fio, post. к колонкам id_department и name_of_department нужно применить агрегирующую функцию LIST (могу ошибиться с названием функции)

Comment: как именно ты хочешь получить данные на выходе? в зависимости от этого ответ будет де-то между «невозможно» и «вероятно, не практично». Опять же, в зависимости от задачи, с большой долей вероятности такую группировку можно выполнить на клиенте при отображении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужная функция называется list:

```
select t.Id_Teacher, t.FIO, t.Post, list(d.Name_Of_Department, ',')
from TEACHERS t
     inner join TEACHERSANDDEPARTMENTS td on (t.Id_Teacher = td.Id_Teacher)
     inner join DEPARTMENTS d on (td.Id_Department = d.Id_Department)
group by t.Id, t.FIO, t.Post
```